# NSMutableString retain/copy are the same(copy doesn't work?)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am testing `copy/retain` property under XCode 6.4 without ARC.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *retainString;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *copyedString;
@synthesize copyedString, retainString;



    NSMutableString *mStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"abc"];
    retainString = mStr;
    copyedString = mStr;
    NSLog(@"mStr:%p",  mStr);
    NSLog(@"retainStr:%p", retainString);
    NSLog(@"copyStr:%p",   copyedString);

    [mStr appendString:@"de"];
    NSLog(@"retainStr:%@",  retainString);
    NSLog(@"copyStr:%@",    copyedString);

    [copyedString appendString:@"123"];
    NSLog(@"mStr:%@",  mStr);
    NSLog(@"copyStr:%@",    copyedString);
    NSLog(@"retainStr:%@",  retainString);
```

My questons:

1. The `copyedString` should alloc a new space, the all the three strings has the same address.
2. When `mString` was changed, `copyedString` shouldn't be changed(I know they are the same address now so changed)
3. `copyedString` changed, `mStr` and `retainString` shouldn't be changed.

Am i make something wrong?

Here are the logs:

```
[10656:986440] mStr:0x7f871bd71340
[10656:986440] retainStr:0x7f871bd71340
[10656:986440] copyStr:0x7f871bd71340
[10656:986440] retainStr:abcde
[10656:986440] copyStr:abcde
[10656:986440] mStr:abcde123
[10656:986440] copyStr:abcde123
[10656:986440] retainStr:abcde123
```

**EDIT** oh yes, my mistake. self.property will call the setter and getter which means copy was used.

So the solution is change these two lines to:

```
self.retainString = mStr;
self.copyedString = mStr;
```

But i got this crash error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Does `copyedString` become `NSString` ?

Comment: `copiedString` and `retainedString` are instance variables. Their mere assignment does not cause a copy, only a retain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use self to access copy property if you want to set value.

```
  NSMutableString *mStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"abc"];

self.retainString = mStr;

self.copyedString = mStr;

NSLog(@"mStr:%p",  mStr);
NSLog(@"retainStr:%p", self.retainString);
NSLog(@"copyStr:%p",   self.copyedString);

[mStr appendString:@"de"];

NSLog(@"retainStr:%@",  self.retainString);
NSLog(@"copyStr:%@",    self.copyedString);
```

Log

```
2015-07-24 16:11:19.728 OCTest[13193:268356] mStr:0x7f84034ba020
2015-07-24 16:11:19.729 OCTest[13193:268356] retainStr:0x7f84034ba020
2015-07-24 16:11:19.729 OCTest[13193:268356] copyStr:0x7f84034bfa50
2015-07-24 16:11:19.729 OCTest[13193:268356] retainStr:abcde
2015-07-24 16:11:19.729 OCTest[13193:268356] copyStr:abc
```

In your way,it not copy,it just use pointer to access the address.So,it point to same address

**Edit**

If you want copy property return mutable result,delete the `@synthesize`,and rewrite

```
-(void)setCopyedString:(NSMutableString *)copyedString{
    _copyedString = [copyedString mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: It crashed,beacuse `-[NSMutableString copy]` return `NSString` that  is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

All of those variables are references to the *same* object:

```
NSMutableString *mStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"abc"];
retainString = mStr;
copyedString = mStr;
```

So changes made via one reference are visible via the other references.

Using the `=` operator, in pretty much any language, does not imply a copy of the object, just a copy of the reference to that object (exception would be an overridden `operator =` in C++, but that's rarely ever done).  This is different for primitive types, where the `=` operator does imply a copy.

What you want, I believe, is:

```
copyedString = [mStr mutableCopy];
```

and now `copyedString` is a different object.

Comment: when mString was assigned to copyedString, it won't alloc a new space for copyedString? If i use [mStr mutableCopy]; why i need "copy" property?

Comment: That's right; as I mention in my answer, using `=` with objects merely copies the reference to the object, not the object itself.  Using the `copy` and `mutableCopy` methods is necessary to *clone* the object.

Comment: '=' copies reference and increase retainCount by 1 for 'retain' property, but for 'copy' it's not, right? I want to test this, but you use 'mutableCopy' no help on what test. Do you think so?